# How could i dynamically bind data in checkbox in mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

- I am working in mvc3 razor.
- i want checkbox input in razor view for all catagories stored in database.
- how could i bind it? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your model is having a field to hold all the checkbox text like.

```
   public class MyClass
{
public string SelectedOptions {get;set;}

public List<String> CheckList {get;set;}

}
```

Write a controller Action method like

```
public ActionResult ShowCheckBoxList()
{
   MyClass Options= new MyClass();
   Options.CheckList  = new List<String>();
   // Here populate the CheckList  with what ever value you have to
   // either if you are getting it from database or hardcoding

   return View(Options);
}
```

you have to create a view by right clicking the above method and choose Add View. Make sure you keep the name same as the method name also you the strongly typed view by choosing the MyClass Model from the dropDown, scaffolding template is optional use it as per your scenario.

Now in your View you can use this populated check box text as

```
 @foreach(var optionText in Model.CheckList)
{
   @Html.CheckBox(@Model.SelectedOptions, false, new {Name = "SelectedOptions", Value = @optionText})
    @Html.Label(@optionText , new { style = "display:inline;" })

}
```

Keep this in a form and make sure you also specify a Action to be called on post of the form.

Make your action name same as the previous action (it is [GET] meaning before post), Now we create same method for [POST]

```
[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult ShowCheckBoxList(MyClass data) // here you will get all the values from UI in data variable 
{
    //data.SelectedOptions  will have all the selected values from checkbox

}
```